# how to get specific key and its value from object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I get specific key and its value from object?

Example I have output of my query:

```
"attribute_summary":"Color: Red",
   "meta_data":[
      {
         "id":5858,
         "key":"_number_field",
         "value":"60,20"
      },
      {
         "id":6275,
         "key":"_mootmed",
         "value":"278 x 138 x 80 mm"
      },
      {
         "id":6276,
         "key":"_kulu",
         "value":"1m2 \/ 26tk"
      },
      {
         "id":6277,
         "key":"_varv_va",
         "value":"hall"
      },
      {
         "id":6278,
         "key":"_alus_al",
         "value":"8,6 m2 \/ 224 tk \/ 1350 kg"
      },
      {
         "id":6279,
         "key":"_alus_mo",
         "value":"1200 x 1200 mm"
      }
   ]
```

And I know if I query like this `$product->attribute_summary;` I can get data `Color: Red`

But How do I get data of `meta_data`? Like need to get key `_alus_al` and its value displayed.

Comment: With `$product->meta_data` you get the meta data array. You can search through that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I dont know whats wrong but it doesnt display `echo $product->meta_data;`

Comment: Try `var_dump($product->meta_data);` instead of `echo $product->meta_data;`. There's something else wrong, that we cannot see in your question, if that doesn't work.

Comment: I get this `String(0) "" `

Comment: Try to work out why you don't get the array. I can't tell from the information in your question.

Comment: `var_dump` of `$product` gives me `["meta_data":protected]=> NULL }` but why

Comment: `protected` means that `meta_data` is not accessible from outside the object. This is usually done by [specifying the visibility of a property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking WooCommerce here.  The way to get the specific meta value from the `$product` Object is simply.

```
add_action('your_action', function(){
   global $product;
   $meta_data = $product->get_meta('your_meta_key'));
});
```

see https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Data.html#method_get_meta for reference.